# How to set the 3D object to the left of the screen

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7C35f.jpg)hope you have a grate day. 
before any one tell me that there is a question like that please knew that I search a lot for my problem and try many solutions but nothing work.
am new at unity and I have problem sitting the object to the left of the screen, I try changing the x axis in C£ script but it goes out of the border  of the screen, I don't know why I have been in this problem for 2 weeks :(
please help me
the image inserted is when I try to move the object to the left but the as you can see the object is goes out of border.

Comment: you need to include your code, a reproducible example, an example of your desired output, what you have tried and any specific errors you are getting. This is way too vague

Answer (score 0):

You probably should add/subtract half the width of the object from the position Vector when you are trying to set it. [ This will only work if the pivot point of your model is at the center of the mesh] or else you should add/subtract the distance from the pivot point to the end of the mesh from the Position vector and then set it.

Comment: can you please explain more , please

Comment: If you can provide me with the code I can tell you where the error is coming from.
I am talking about something like this :https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ailbszpt_AI
You can see that he is considering the (width/2) of the sprite while trying to keep it within bounds.

Comment: void LateUpdate()
    {
        Vector3 pos = Camera.main.WorldToViewportPoint(transform.position);
        pos.x = Mathf.Clamp01(pos.x);
        pos.y = Mathf.Clamp01(pos.y);
        transform.position = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(pos);


    }    @Ashokkumar thats my code

Comment: # Get the left bottom corner of the camera in world coordinates
Vector3 cameraWorld = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0,0,camera.nearClipPlane));

# add the bounds of the mesh to the world coordinates
cameraWorld.x += transform.GetComponent.<Renderer>().bounds.size.x/2;
cameraWorld.y += transform.GetComponent.<Renderer>().bounds.size.y/2;

# set the position of the transform
transform.position = cameraWorld.position

Comment: the code above have a lot of errors, that I Couldn't  solve